# Delete [accesibility] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, accessibility

The tag [accesibility] is a misspelled version of the [accessibility] tag. I would suggest this to be deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On inspection it turned out that only one question had that misspelled tag. I therefor submitted [an edit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/131725/revisions) so the tag was no longer used on any question. Once the [edit was reviewed and approved](https://ux.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59732) there were zero questions with the misspelled tag.

After 03:00 UTC the system runs a cleanup batch to remove so called ["zombie" tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).

The timing of all actions was perfect as the tag is now indeed gone.